# Delayed evaluation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, delay, lazy-evaluation

I'm having some trouble understanding how the `delay` macro works in Clojure. It doesn't seem to do what expect it to do (that is: delaying evaluation). As you can see in this code sample:

```
; returns the current time
(defn get-timestamp [] (System/currentTimeMillis))

; var should contain the current timestamp after calling "force"
(def current-time (delay (get-timestamp)))
```

However, calling `current-time` in the REPL appears to immediately evaluate the expression, even without having used the `force` macro:

```
user=> current-time
#<Delay@19b5217: 1276376485859>
user=> (force current-time)
1276376485859
```

Why was the evaluation of `get-timestamp` not delayed until the first `force` call?

Comment: minor comment: it's better to use (System/currentTimeMillis) directly rather than constructing a Date - they use the same underlying millisecond source but the former avoids an unnecessary object allocation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The printed representation of various objects which appears at the REPL is the product of a multimethod called `print-method`. It resides in the file `core_print.clj` in Clojure's sources, which constitutes part of what goes in the `clojure.core` namespace.

The problem here is that for objects implementing `clojure.lang.IDeref` -- the Java interface for things `deref` / `@` can operate on -- `print-method` includes the value behind the object in the printed representation. To this end, it needs to `deref` the object, and although special provisions are made for printing failed Agents and pending Futures, Delays are always forced.

Actually I'm inclined to consider this a bug, or at best a situation in need of an improvement. As a workaround for now, take extra care not to print unforced delays.

Comment: I will of course try to make the improvement happen. It should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I guess the Heisenberg Principle applies to clojure also: you can't observe the delay without changing it. :-)

Comment: @Greg: I think you mean the Observer Effect. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)#Quantum_mechanics